# NHibernate CreateSQLQuery data conversion from bit to boolean error

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

Im being a bit lazy in NHibernate and using Session.CreateSqlQuery(...) instead of doing the whole thing with Lambda's. Anyway what struct me is that there seems to be a problem converting some of the types returned from (in this case the MySQL) DB into native .Net tyes.

The query in question looks like this....

```
     IList<Client> allocatableClients =
                    Session.CreateSQLQuery(
                      "select clients.id as Id, clients.name as Name, clients.customercode as CustomerCode, clients.superclient as SuperClient, clients.clienttypeid as ClientType " +
...
...
.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Client))).List<Client>();
```

The type in the database of SuperClient is a bit(1) and in the Client object the type is a bool.

The error received is:

```
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.UInt64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Boolean'.
```

It seems strange that this conversion cannot be completed.

Would be greatful for any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do any lambdas (even though they are fun!). If `Client` is a mapped class then you can use the core NHibernate method `CreateCriteria<>`. It is very simple:

```
session
    .CreateCriteria<Client>()
    .List<Client>();
```

If `Client` isn't mapped then I would create a property `SuperUser_Long` and wrap it with `SuperUser`

Comment: My bad! I should have included the rest of my query which has some where clauses which I wanted to avoid "lambda-ing."

Comment: No need for lambdas on the where clause either :) - use `.Add()` on the `CreateCriteria` to add a `SimpleExpression` or a `Restriction`